# Queryset filtering on Foreignkey in Modelform

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a strange issue when saving a model form. I have a form, which consists of two model forms and I am trying to save them at the same time. For clarity, below is my code

**Views.py**

```
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        my_user_form = MyUsersForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and my_user_form.is_valid():
           us = user_form.save()
           my_us = my_user_form.save(commit=False)
           my_us.user = us
           my_us.save()
           return HttpResponse('You have successfully created a user')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(' My_user_form is not validated')

    else:
         user_form = UserForm()
         my_user_form = MyUsersForm(user=request.user)
         return render(request, 'create_user.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'my_user_form': my_user_form})
```

my_user_form is not validated when I override the **init** method of MyUsersForm to filter the queryset of the foreign key(created_by) but when I don"t filter the queryset, my_user_form is validated and the form is saved.

What I don't understand is when I don"t filter the query set how come my_user_form is validated?

The data which is sent via the request.post to my_user_form is somehow lost (when I filter the queryset). any clue in the right direction is highly appreciated. Thank you for your valuable inputs.

**Forms.py**

```
class MyUsersForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyUsers
        fields = ['created_by', ]

    def __init__(self, user=None, **kwargs):
        super(MyUsersForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields['created_by'].queryset = User.objects.filter(username=user)
```

**Models.py**

```
class MyUsers(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="created_by", blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: What do you mean by not validated? What are you trying to validate?

Comment: i am trying to validate the data which is sent to my_user_form = MyUsersForm(request.POST), which is basically a User object. Unfortunately, the User object is not getting validated (even though the user is in the database and shown in the dropdown menu in the get request.) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why my_user_form is not validated and saved. instead of modifying the queryset in the **init** i did it in the **view** itself using the statement

```
my_user_form.fields['created_by'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(User.objects.filter(username=request.user))
```

and this solves my problem. but i still don't know why it didn't work in the init method of the MyUsersForm?.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        my_user_form = MyUsersForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and my_user_form.is_valid() and User.objects.filter(username=request.POST.get('user')).exists():
           us = user_form.save()
           my_us = my_user_form.save(commit=False)
           my_us.user = us
           my_us.save()
           return HttpResponse('You have successfully created a user')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(' My_user_form is not validated')

    else:
         user_form = UserForm()
         my_user_form = MyUsersForm(user=request.user)
         return render(request, 'create_user.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'my_user_form': my_user_form})
```

Comment: You can write a clean method or in views you can check

Comment: User.objects.filter(username=request.POST.get('user')).exists() only checks the user is in the database. In my case, the user is the database and he is  authenticated to perform his task. any inputs about writing the clean method?

Comment: In your forms you can write a clean method to validate

Comment: def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['user']
        if User.objects.filter(username__iexact=username).exists():
            raise ValidationError(u'%s already exists' % username)

Comment: you can try @login_required decorator which authenticates the user so if you have logged in then only it allows to perform the operations